# Couldn't able to initialise and push Github repository directly from Atom IDE

Tags: github, ide, atom-editor

I'm new to Atom Editor. Currently working on a PHP project which needs to push into the Github repo. I have initialized the project folder using git init command in the Atom IDE terminal itself. When I try to push the changes into the git. I throw various error messages I followed the command given in the terminal but doesn't work either.

When I tried to execute `git push` I get below error message

> fatal: '' does not appear to be a git repository

Then I executed `git init` again and `git commit -m "message"` but again it asked me to upstream the changes I did the same using below command

```
git push --set-upstream master master
```

Keep on getting these two errors.

[image]

Comment: What are the `various error messages`?

Comment: have updated with the error messages @CaddyDZ

Comment: Run `git init` in your `project name`

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE somehow fails, step back and go to the command line (shell or CMD)

In the root folder of your project, check that there is a `.git/` subfolder.

Type `git remote -v`.

If you do not see an entry "`origin`" with the URL of your remote repo, type:

```
git remote add origin /url/remote/repo
```

You should see:

```
C:\Users\vonc\git\go-prompt>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/VonC/go-prompt (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/VonC/go-prompt (push)
```

Then, assuming you have added/committed file, try again the

```
git push -u origin master
# not master master, but origin master
```

Comment: I tried the way you have suggested but getting below issues. Can you kindly help me on this? kindly find the image attached in the question section

Comment: @GopiP I see "link" in your picture: you should see "origin". Can you check my edited answer? I have included an example.

Comment: @GopiP DXC? I am working with you guys! (as a client of DXC services)

Comment: Good to hear from you @VonC. I was in DXC but a few months back I left. I hope you would have seen the image attached and can you help me to rectify the issue

Comment: @GopiP Yes, I have seen the image: my previous comment is about that image.

Comment: let me try and get back to you.